# Image_url always null with Rails 7 API and Active Storage + React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, api

I can't figure out where the problem is, image_url is always null when creating a project.

When I check in the console with:
`Project.last.image_url`

I get this:

```
Project Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 58], ["record_type", "Project"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**API**:

{
"id": "58",
"type": "project",
"attributes": {
"id": 58,
"user_id": 11,
"title": "This is a test",
"content": "This is a test",
"date": "2022-12-22",
"address": "This is a test",
"city": "This is a test",
"postal_code": "This is a test",
"project_status_id": 1,
"region_id": 1,
"country_id": 78,
"image_url": null
}

## **RAILS**:

**Controllers**:
`projects_controller.rb`

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: %i[ show update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[create update destroy]

  # GET /projects
  def index
    if params[:search_term]
      if params[:search_term] == 'user'
        if current_user
          @projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id)
        else
          render json:{message: 'You are not logged in'}, status: :unprocessable_entity
          return
        end
      else
        @regions = Region.where('lower(name) LIKE :prefix', prefix: "#{params[:search_term].downcase}%")
        @countries = Country.where('lower(name) LIKE :prefix', prefix: "#{params[:search_term].downcase}%")
        @projects = Project.where('lower(city) LIKE :prefix', prefix: "#{params[:search_term].downcase}%") 
        @countries.each do |country|
          @projects += Project.where(country_id: country.id)
        end
        @regions.each do |region|
          @projects += Project.where(region_id: region.id)
        end
      end
    else
      @projects = Project.all.distinct
    end
    render json: ProjectSerializer.new(@projects).serializable_hash[:data]
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  def show
    render json: {project: @project, country:@project.country.name, region: @project.region.name, status: @project.project_status.name, comments: @project.comments.includes(:user).select('id, content, user, user_id, created_at'), likes: @project.likes.select('id, user_id'), project_registrations: @project.project_registrations.select('id, user_id')}
  end

  # POST /projects
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project
    else
      render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  def update
    if @project.user_id == current_user.id || current_user.admin 
      country_id = Country.find_by(name: params[:project][:country]).id
      region_id = Region.find_by(name: params[:project][:region]).id
      project_status_id = ProjectStatus.find_by(name: params[:project][:project_status]).id
      if @project.update(project_params) && @project.update(country_id:country_id, region_id:region_id, project_status_id:project_status_id)
        render json: @project
      else
        render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      render json: { message: 'You are not the creator of this project.'}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :content, :user_id, :project_status_id, :date, :address, :city, :postal_code, :GPS, :region_id, :country_id, :image).except(:region, :country, :project_status)
    end
end
```

**Model**:
`project.rb`

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  belongs_to :project_status
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
  has_many :project_registrations
  validates :title, :content, :user, :content, :region, :country, :project_status, presence: true
  validates :title,
  length: {
    minimum: 2
  }, allow_nil: false
  validates :content,
  length: {
    minimum: 5
  }, allow_nil: false

  def image_url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image) if image.attached?
  end
end
```

**Serializer**:
`project_serializer.rb`

```
class ProjectSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user_id, :title, :content, :date, :address, :city, :postal_code, :project_status_id, :region_id, :country_id, :image_url
end
```

## **REACT**:

```
function FileForm() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const countryOptions = useAtomValue(countriesAtom);
  const regionOptions = useAtomValue(regionsAtom);
  const projectStatusesOptions = useAtomValue(projectStatusesAtom);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("project[user_id]", currentUserId());
    data.append("project[title]", event.target.title.value);
    data.append("project[content]", event.target.content.value);
    data.append("project[date]", event.target.date.value);
    data.append("project[address]", event.target.address.value);
    data.append("project[city]", event.target.city.value);
    data.append("project[postal_code]", event.target.postal_code.value);
    data.append("project[project_status_id]", event.target.status.value);
    data.append("project[region_id]", event.target.region.value);
    data.append("project[country_id]", event.target.country.value);
    data.append("project[image]", event.target.image.files[0]);
    try {
      await APIManager.newProject(data);
      navigate("/myprojects");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>File Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
          <input type="text" name="content" id="content" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
          <input type="date" name="date" id="date" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
          <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="postal_code">Postal Code</label>
          <input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="project_status_id">Status</label>
          <select id="status" name="status">
            {projectStatusesOptions.map((projectStatusesOption) => {
              return (
                <option
                  key={projectStatusesOption.id + projectStatusesOption.name}
                  value={projectStatusesOption.id}
                >
                  {projectStatusesOption.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="region_id">Region</label>
          <select id="region" name="region">
            {regionOptions.map((regionOption) => {
              return (
                <option
                  key={regionOption.id + regionOption.name}
                  value={regionOption.id}
                >
                  {regionOption.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label htmlFor="country_id">Country</label>
          <select id="country" name="country">
            {countryOptions.map((countryOption) => {
              return (
                <option
                  key={countryOption.id + countryOption.name}
                  value={countryOption.id}
                >
                  {countryOption.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="image-container">
          <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create project" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileForm;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with axios, it's now working perfectly.
In the headers I replaced `"application/json"` by `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`